# ACL2's GL clock ran out

Tags: acl2

What does it mean when I receive the following error message?  I have GL loaded.

```
| ACL2 Error in ( DEFTHM SOME-THEOREM-THAT-USES-GL ...):  The clock
| ran out.~%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that while you have GL loaded, you haven't yet defined a clause-processor that includes all of the necessary symbolic counterparts.  This can occur even if you've already defined a GL clause processor -- you have likely included some other books since defining the GL clause processor.

To solve it, simply define yet another GL clause processor:

```
(def-gl-clause-processor yet-another-gl-clause-processor)
```